# Uploading a file to Sharepoint from a client browser

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint

I have a web server not running Sharepoint and it does not even use any Microsoft technology. I need a way to for browsers accessing my website to be able to also upload a local file (local to client) to a Sharepoint service visible to the client and then send the status to my web server. I do not want to run stand alone apps on the client. How can I accomplish this? I am a newbie to web programming, so please bear with me if this question does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unusual situation.

If your users can access the Sharepoint website and upload the files there, then you can subscribe to the folder where the files are updated, and receive notification emails from Sharepoint. If those emails go to a dedicated email address on your web server, you can process those incoming emails in an app on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize the answer from DOK, you can enable workflow on the document library that they're uploading to. This can trigger any action or series of actions that you might like.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your circumstance that you rarely do not use any Microsoft technology, I am not optimize that you can do that simply uploading or downloading in a usual way. My experience tells me that there are always some hurdles if you do not use MS technology.

I am not a much experienced SharePoint users, and have not met your situation. However I strongly believe DOK's answer is better for you.

Hope this helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

From the client, you have to use SharePoint client OM. From the browser, you can choose javascript or C# from a Silverlight control. See [Using the SharePoint Foundation 2010 Managed Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a cross-site scripting issue. I think your best bet would be to have the user enter the filename/url into your web application rather than attempt to write script to automate that notification. Your server could use WebDAV or call sharepoint to verify the file exists.